No fluent terrain collision OpenGL
I am making a OpenGL videogame in C++. I have the mesh of the irregular terrain and I have the player who walks around the world adjusting to the heightmap. The problem is that the movement is very artificial, as it moves, it makes small jumps adjusting to the mesh, which spoils the gaming experience.
There is the code to obtain the height of the mesh, it basically makes a bilinear interpolation:
//Obtains the height of the terrain (Y coordinate)
//with a bilinear interpolation
double Terrain::getYLocation(double x, double z) {
    double x1 = (int)x + ((1.0f / this->terrainMeshDensity) * getOffset(x));
    double z1 = (int)z + ((1.0f / this->terrainMeshDensity) * getOffset(z));
    double x2 = x1 + 1.0f;
    double z2 = z1 + 1.0f;

    int xIndex = (int)x;
    int zIndex = (int)z * this->terrainMeshDensity + getOffset(z);

    double q11 = this->meshPoints[30 * this->terrainMeshDensity * (zIndex * this->size + xIndex) + 1];
    double q12 = this->meshPoints[30 * this->terrainMeshDensity * (zIndex * this->size + xIndex) + 6];
    double q21 = this->meshPoints[30 * this->terrainMeshDensity * (zIndex * this->size + xIndex) + 11];
    double q22 = this->meshPoints[30 * this->terrainMeshDensity * (zIndex * this->size + xIndex) + 26];

    return ((q11 * ((double)x2 - x) * ((double)z2 - z)) + (q21 * (x - (double)x1) * ((double)z2 - z)) + (q12 * ((double)x2 - x) * (z - (double)z1)) + (q22 * (x - (double)x1) * (z - (double)z1)));
}

And this is the movement:
void Player::teclaW() {
    this->position_Z += this->sensitivity * sin(M_PI / 180 * this->angleRotation_X);
    this->position_X += this->sensitivity * cos(M_PI / 180 * this->angleRotation_X);
    this->position_Y = this->terrain->getYLocation(this->position_X, this->position_Z) + 3;
}

I tried to increase the precision, and do a lineal interpolation between the old position and the new position to reduce this jumps but nothing works correctly.
There is any problem with this bilinear interpolation? Or there is another form to obtain the height?
